# How can I make it so that my increments and decrements system works correctly?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I'm trying to create a likes system similar to Instagram but the problem is that with my code, the `$incrementDecrementLike` value keeps incrementing by `1` despite having that if condition.

how can I make it so that when testing on Postman, every time I make the request - it increments/decrements by `1` indefinitely?

#### Controller:

```
public function incrementDecrementLike(Request $request)
{
    $userId = $request->get('UserID');
    $likeCount = $request->get('likeCount'); // the amount of times the user clicked the like button 
    $getUserLikes = $this->__usersRepository->getUserLikes($userId); 
    $userLikes = $getUserLikes[0]->likes; // get the the user's total amount of likes to increment 

    if ($likeCount >= 1) {
        $userLikes--;
        $this->__usersRepository->incrementDecrementLike($userId, $userLikes, $likeCount);
    }

    $userLikes++;
    $incrementDecrementLike = $this->__usersRepository->incrementDecrementLike($userId, $userLikes, $likeCount);

    return ['incrementDecrementLikes' => $incrementDecrementLike];
}
```

#### Repository:

```
public function incrementDecrementLike($userId, $userLikes, $likeCount)
{
    $data = ['likes' => $likeCount > 1 ? $userLikes - 1 : $userLikes + 1];
    DB::table('uploads')
        ->where('UserID', $userId)
        ->update($data);
    
    return $data['likes'];
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't tell the database how many likes the user should have, you should only tell it to increase/decrease, something like: `SET likes = likes + 1`. Your current code can end up with race conditions if you're unlucky and two people likes at the exact same time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be with the logic and flow of your if-checks.

These lines:

```
if($likeCount >= 1) {
   $userLikes--;
   $this->__usersRepository->incrementDecrementLike($userId, $userLikes, $likeCount);
}

$userLikes++;
$incrementDecrementLike =   ...
```

are saying 'if they push the button twice, decrement', but **no matter what** increment.  You are coming out of the if-check and incrementing always.  It might be helpful to add an `else` before the `$userLikes++;` line to wrap that in the check logic.

You might also consider reducing the complexity of this whole thing.  A repo + table DB + pretty large code might be better suited as with a simple property on the User, maybe ' `likes` ' and then, following a calculation, just update the model something like:

```
$user->update(['likes' => $amount]);
```